# Backslash in endpoint

Tags: rest, url, soapui, endpoint

I need to consume an endpoint from SoapUI which contains a backslash like:

`mydomain/myservice/{id_resource}`

and the assignment:

`id_resource = numbers\numbers`

The problem here is that when I executed the request, the consumed url is `mydomain/myservice/numbers%40%5Cnumbers`, and if I check the option of disabling the URL-encoding, it ignores the backslash () between the numbers of the `id_resource`, going to an url like `mydomain/myservice/numbersnumbers`.

I've tried to scape the character with another backslash, like java or other languages, but it doesn´t work.

It works fine if I consume the service with postman, so it is not a problem of the logic consumed.

So, is it possible to consume an url containing a backslash from SoapUI?

Comment: Please see if this is relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201838/using-a-backslash-5c-in-a-rest-wcf-url

Comment: No, there the provided solution is to change the delimiter character, but I can't change it because it is not under my control, I just receive the identifier, but I can't change it. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to disable URL encoding for the selected parameter which would assist with this.

https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/reference/method-window.html