# Jersey URL Mapping

Tags: java, jersey, restful-url

We have a Jersey resource with following mapping.

```
@GET
@Path("{key}/{ignored:.*}")
@Produces(MediaType.WILDCARD)
public Response getKeyCodes(@PathParam("key") final String key) {
   String output = "Jersey say : " + key;
   return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

Idea is to match every url to this get resource and consider first part of the url as key.

Its mostly working except for following url. For this request I am receiving 400 Bad request. Any ideas why its not working?

http://localhost:8080/rest/hello/8a439079fea971592e905451b81abec883c767f7/Hamilton-Beach-17201-Steam-Irons%5C-BlueWhite.jpg

I also noted if we remove %5C(when decoded its "\") from the above url is working. Any further insight on this would greatly helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

That is perfectly fine. I guess your method is looking for some file with name `Hamilton-Beach-17201-Steam-Irons\-BlueWhite.jpg` and because `\` is encoded to `%C` your literal string search at service may not be working as you have to decide the string.

Comment: I really do not have any code in my method. For better understanding have edited my question and added all my method code. All I noticed is its never going to my method.

Comment: Then check your setting. The value of path is auto URL decoded unless this is disabled using the Encoded annotation. I do not see that hence your server shall be recieving Hamilton-Beach-17201-Steam-Irons\-BlueWhite.jpg . Print the value at server if value received in encoded URL is not decoded as expected. @anil

Comment: No luck the request is not even reaching my rest resource or Jersey servlet class "ServletContainer.java"

Comment: Shall you not give slash regex in your path key itself {key :.+} itself. If that doesn't work, I will share a working jersey service in sometime printing values.

Comment: I modified my code as suggested and it still didn't work. I don't think its the problem with my code as the request is not even coming to Jersey servlet service method.

Comment: Seems like we shouldn't be assigning %5C for path variables. It can only be used for query parameters. Following post had some information about it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201838/using-a-backslash-5c-in-a-rest-wcf-url

But thanks for trying to help me. Appreciated.

Comment: Dear @Anil, while I appreciate your research, I just tried exact same service as yours(only modified `msg` to key in `String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;` and got the response as  : `Jersey say : 8a439079fea971592e905451b81abec883c767f7` 

So it might not be issue with your service but the client you are using. Try invoking the URL and chrome and you shall see the response. I tried with jersey 2.

there is no reason why encoding URL shall not work.

Comment: Further analysis indicated the issue is with Tomcat. We had to include couple of java opts to rectify this problem. I guess you were testing on some other web server.