# Backslash not recognized as param in WebGet

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Code:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "ProgrammerData/Document/{*documentName}")]
string ProgrammerDataDocument(string documentName);
```

Call:

[image: call]
Image text: `localhost/RedactedPath/ProgrammerData/Document/%5C%5Cxundas`

Result

[image]
Image Text:

```
public string ProgrammerDataDocument(string documentName)
{
  // value of documentName at this point is "xundas"
  string a = "";
  return a;
}
```

The backslash I encoded but is not appearing in my param.

I need this because I send a network path from my client side to my server

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201838/using-a-backslash-5c-in-a-rest-wcf-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, the backslash is not supported by the browser when we pass the backslash to the server. any backslash would be converted to forward slash. thereby this is impossible to achieve.
Besides, both forward slash and backslash placed before the parameter are not recognized (not encrypted yet), but slashes placed in the middle of the parameter are recognized and automatically converted to backslash. Finally, when the result is returned, the Url supports forward slash. Please consider the below code.

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate ="abc/{*value}")]
        string GetData(string value);


    public string GetData(string value)
            {
                var result = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(value);
                result = result.Replace("/", @"\\");
                return result;
            }
```

Result.
[image]
About the UriTemplate.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/uritemplate-and-uritemplatetable?redirectedfrom=MSDN
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes are not allowed in the resource name of a URL (browsers simply convert them to forwards slashes); they are only allowed as encoded value of a query parameter.

I suggest to brach out the domain part and the name part in your path, e.g.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "ProgrammerData/Document/{docDomain}{docName}")]
string ProgrammerDataDocument(string docDomain, string docName);
```

You may want to add a slash as separator between the domain/UNC part (which is empty, so basically, `.`, i.e. `local` in your example) and the document name which makes sense from a hierarchical perspective.